# Boot editing in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot

How do I perform boot editing in Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you want to edit? if you just want to change the boot load order on a dual boot system, you can use Control panel/Advanced Settings/Advanced/Startup and recovery.

if you want to modify start-up parameters you could use msconfig, just run the command from  start menu/run.

if you want more options use BCDedit, which you run from the command prompt, just run bcdedit /? for help. There's also a similar [utility](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) called EasyBCD but it has a graphical UI

Comment: If you liked his reply, you should click the checkmark next to it, to mark it as the correct answer.